# Commit failed: "Repository UUID '...' doesn't match expected UUID '...'" when committing to Google Code from Eclipse on Windows

Tags: eclipse, svn

I was able to work with all my projects on Google Code just fine, but now I can't commit to any of them.  I get the error:

> Some of selected resources were not committed. svn: Commit failed
>   (details follow): svn: Repository UUID
>   '2b3ccc6c-acbf-642b-775e-b44874e3cfdd' doesn't match expected UUID
>   '2b06ef8f-344e-f67a-312d-ecb7346c3921'

(I am using Eclipse on Windows)

The same error occurs when I update.

Comment: Just a thought, can you do a fresh check out and use a merge tool to manually merge changes, and commit normally when done?

Answer (score 5):

You can fix this by correcting the UUID of the repository in the local SQLite3 subversion database. To do that, download sqlite3 from here:

http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

And put it somewhere on PATH so that the system knows about it. Then open the command prompt or your terminal (if you're on linux) in the directory that contains the repository .svn directory. Then open the subversion database file for editing like this:

```
sqlite3 .svn/wc.db
```

This will start a command a command line accepting SQL commands. Type in this command, replacing the UUID with the one that shows in your error message:

```
update REPOSITORY set uuid="2b3ccc6c-acbf-642b-775e-b44874e3cfdd" where id=1
```

Hit enter and CTRL+C to quit. Now you should be able to run your svn commit command again.

Answer (score 2):

Your Working Copy is linked to Repository, which must have unique Identificator (UUID), which stored as a part of metadata in Working Copy and identity of stored UUID and contacted Repo's UUID is tested on operations, which can modify repository

For some reason, you try to communicate not to the same repository, from which your WC was created (same URL != same Repo)

Verify current UUIDs with `svn info WC-PATH` and `svn info REPO-URL` (REPO-URL for main repo and all "foreign", if externals used)

`Repository UUID` value **must be** the same

Comment: Yes, but you must explain how make them the same. In my case, the repository was recreated after the server was reinstalled, so it acquired new UUIDs on all repos. THE URI OF THE REPO HAS *NOT* CHANGED. How should I tell the working copies that they must stay using the existing URIs but must expect the new UUIDs?

Comment: @PeterFlynn: 1) I **must** nothing (!) you or anybody here 2) I *can* explain, how SVN-admin must make his own job, but it's different question. In short: you can't use old WC with new UUID of repo (even it it's sing;e change of data) and have to have old UUID. Period

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem when I tried to commit two files at once that belonged to separate external repositories. I tried committing them separately and succeeded.